# Dashboard for Azure multi-stage pipeline? Status widgets only support aggregate results?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline, azure-devops-multistage-pipeline

My question is about creating test results Dashboard for Azure multi-stage pipeline?

It seems that the built-in Azure Dashboard widgets only support aggregate results, on a per-repo basis, in aggregate for all stages of a pipeline?

Q: Is there a way to collect results from all 3 stages of a 3 stage pipeline, **separately**, so I can see status of each stage independently?

OR , is there a way to do a command line call to get per-stage results info?

OR, is there a 3rd party solution?

Jenkins can do this, so why not Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you could try to use the REST API to get the stage's status to check if it meets your requirements.

For more information, you can refer to: [How to get stage results from YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58124834/how-to-get-stage-results-from-yaml-pipelines-in-azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks.  Been a long time since I got a good answer on StackExchange.

Comment: This project gets me part of the way there: https://github.com/hkarthik7/azure-devops-java-sdk   .  That project doesn't have support for "test runs" though and so I will need to code some stuff organically to achieve this.